# Django Admin - How to convert delete action dropdown in a single button

Tags: javascript, django

I would like to 'transform' the action dropdown, that have the default delete option, in a single button, but keeping the rule of delete all the row that are checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by overriding the default action form as :

```
class CustomActionForm(forms.Form):
    action = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput,
                             initial='delete_selected',
                             label='Delete Selected'
                             )
    select_across = forms.BooleanField(
                                       label='',
                                       required=False,
                                       initial=0,
                                       widget=forms.HiddenInput({'class': 'select-across'}),
                                       )
```

Then in your admin class define this as:

```
class YourAdminClass(admin.ModelAdmin):
     action_form = CustomActionForm
     ......
```

Now this custom action form will remove the action select dropdown and you would be able to use only `delete_selected` action.
 It will look something like this:

[image]

If you want further customization in the template, you may consider overriding `actions.html`.

Hope this helps.